# Using an M1 Mac mini with HDMI to DVI adapter

Tags: display, mac-mini, hdmi, apple-silicon, dvi

I have been trying unsuccessfully to get my M1 Mac mini (M1, 2020, running 13.2 (22D49) Ventura) working with an older DVI monitor.

My current configuration has my primary (4K) monitor hooked up via a Thunderbolt to HDMI cable and it works great. I was using an HDMI-to-HDMI before and that worked great as well.

My secondary monitor is an HD display (1920x1080, [LG W2240](https://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-W2240S-lcd-monitor)S LCD monitor) with DVI-D and VGA inputs.  I cannot get this display to work properly with the Mac mini.  I attempted to use an HDMI-to-DVI adaptor and that results in the image below.

[image: messed up display on an HD monitor]

It's hard to see in the image, but the display seems shifted to the right by about half an inch of where it ought to be.

I was previously using this display with an older Mac mini over the HDMI-to-DVI cable and it worked fine. I am currently using the VGA port to connect to a PC and that works as well. I did try switching the HDMI-to-DVI input to the PC and that works. The only case that doesn't seem to work is the Mac mini to the older monitor.

Just for kicks I grabbed an HDMI-to-VGA cable and tried that. That made the Mac mini go crazy as it seemed to think that the 4K monitor was both displays, nothing showed up in the HD monitor in that configuration.

Interestingly enough, when the monitor wakes from sleep, some of the time it is just displaying random "static." When it is in this state the display doesn't appear shifted, but it doesn't really display anything useful at all.

I'm looking for any suggestions or directions for what to try.

Addressing comments:

> What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? From what I read in
> the question, both monitors work fine when you use the digital
> connections (HDMI and DVI) but fails when you use the analog (VGA)
> with the Mac Studio that’s also driving a 4K monitor. Assuming the
> second monitor supports XGA, you’re limited to 1024x768 - barely HD.
> Why is necessary to connect the Studio to the VGA port?

I am attempting to use my older HD monitor as a secondary monitor to the newer 4K monitor.  It does not work with either the HDMI-to-DVI cable or with the the HDMI-to-VGA cable when connected to the M1 mini.  I have tried both of these signal paths with other computers and the monitor display works just fine.  This monitor is capable of 1920x1080 over VGA and I have used it this way in the past.  There is no need to use the VGA port, I would prefer to use DVI, but I figured if DVI didn't work but VGA did I'd still be set.

> Studio/mini…just a typo; no difference to the Q. The image shift came
> after the “just for kicks…HDMI to VGA…” statement so we can infer it’s
> when using this mode unless the OP clarifies. It still makes no sense
> to use a 4K and a VGA secondary - the resolutions will be too
> different to be effective.

The image shift is when using the (preferred) DVI input on the monitor.  This is also the configuration in the above picture.  I tried the VGA input to see if that would work.  It doesn't even get as far as with the DVI port.

I consider the pairing of a 4K monitor with a full HD monitor being ineffective to be subjective and it suits my needs just fine.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?  From what I read in the question, both monitors work fine when you use the digital connections (HDMI and DVI) but fails when you use the analog (VGA) with the Mac Studio that’s also driving a 4K monitor.  Assuming the second  monitor supports XGA, you’re limited to 1024x768 - barely HD.  Why is necessary to connect the Studio to the VGA port?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - Studio/mini…just a typo; no difference to the Q.  The image shift came after the “just for kicks…HDMI to VGA…” statement so we can infer it’s when using this mode unless the OP clarifies.  It still makes no sense to use a 4K and a VGA secondary - the resolutions will be too different to be effective.

Comment: @allan I can easily think of setups where a lowres secondary screen might be useful. Let‘s see whether we can help the OP with this, or whether we are looking at a hardware/macOS issue.

Comment: @nohillside, my comment was made prior to the OP’s subsequent edit and connecting to VGA wasn’t anywhere close to “full HD” per the OP’s wished. Since we got additional info since then, my educated guess as to the problem here is that it’s a sync issue.